# Different between addOne and upsertOne in ngrx/entity angular 7

Tags: angular, entity, adapter, ngrx

As I know about docs of ngrx/entity adapter

addOne: Add one entity to the collection
upsertOne: Add or Update one entity in the collection
updateOne: Update one entity in the collection

Why do we need upsertOne here while we have addOne and updateOne?
So can I use only upsertOne for both case: add new item or update new item? The docs makes me confused a bit

Comment: As of NgRx v9 there is also the `setOne` method: [relevant v9 docs](https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods)

Answer (score 3):

`updateOne`: add the entity to the collection, does nothing if the entity is already in the store state
`upsertOne`: add the entity to the collection, updates the existing entity in the store if it's already present

Comment: hi @imdeschryver:
you mean:
updateOne: not cause view to re render
upsertOne: will make view rerender ?

2. Why we don't use upsertOne to cover updateOne?

Comment: upsertOne  will create an entity if it doesn't exist in the collection, whereas updateOn will do nothing because the entity is not in the collection. 
Rerender will only occur when the state changes, so  methods cause a new render.

Comment: As per the latest NgRx documentation- `updateOne`: Update one entity in the collection. Supports partial updates.
So `updateOne` doesn't add the entity to the collection if not present